# SQL Server: round a percentage to nearest whole number

Tags: sql-server, rounding, percentage

I've looked at some of the answers here, and I keep getting stuck. I'm a brand new beginner.

I have a simple select statement

```
SELECT (100.0*(CURRENRL)/(CAPACITY)) AS "OCCUPANCY RATE"
FROM COURSE, LOCATION
WHERE LOCATION.LOCID=COURSE.LOCID
```

returns a column

```
90.000000000000
100.000000000000
80.000000000000
100.000000000000
100.000000000000
59.523809523809
66.666666666666
28.571428571428
76.190476190476
83.333333333333
23.333333333333
```

I'm just trying to round to the nearest whole number.

Such that I get output like:

```
90
100
80
100
100
60
67
...
```

I've tried to use ROUND and CAST, but end up with errors every time. I can post the errors if necessary, but my guess is that this should be simple and I'm missing some formatting or similar from the other questions I've looked at here on SO.

If I do:

```
ROUND(100.0*(CURRENRL)/(CAPACITY), 0) AS "OCCUPANCY RATE"
```

I get a lot of decimal places.

If I do:

```
ROUND(100*(CURRENRL)/(CAPACITY), 0) AS "OCCUPANCY RATE"
```

I get a nice whole integer, but it doesn't seem to round correctly. For instance, I get 59 instead of 60 for the 6th number, and 66 instead of 67 for the 7th number, etc.

Comment: Help us help you - share your attempt and the error you got when trying

Comment: @Mureinik - added.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Thank you!  That helps my understanding and further development.  I'm just a lowly Infrastructure guy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SELECT CEILING(66.666666666666) gives 67, from your statement:

```
SELECT CEILING(100*(CURRENRL)/(CAPACITY)) AS "OCCUPANCY RATE"
FROM COURSE, LOCATION
WHERE LOCATION.LOCID=COURSE.LOCID
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.  This works to get the rounding, but I was looking for rounding and then just displaying the whole integer, no decimal places.  Take a look at my edit

Comment: @TheCleaner  I edited my answer. Just use Round with no number afterwards. Please vote if its correct.

Comment: Using that I get "The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments"

Comment: @TheCleaner Here is the real answer :). My bad I thought it said "MY SQL" lol.

Answer (score 3):

How about a combination using cast and round? after rounding off, switch it to INT to get the whole number.

```
SELECT **CAST(** _ROUND(100.0*(CURRENRL)/(CAPACITY)), 0)_ **AS INT)** AS "OCCUPANCY RATE"
FROM COURSE, LOCATION
WHERE LOCATION.LOCID=COURSE.LOCID
```

---

BUT also tested the edited answer of E Alexis T using ceiling and it also gives your desired answer. It's far better than my answer in terms of shorter code :) It should be your choice. It just has a flaw in rounding lower than 5. example 123.39 still goes to 124.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it as below.
First, round your results, then you convert it to int. It will automatically remove the zeros to the right

```
select convert(int,round((100.0*(CURRENRL)/(CAPACITY)) ,0)) AS "OCCUPANCY RATE"
FROM COURSE, LOCATION
WHERE LOCATION.LOCID=COURSE.LOCID
```